# Do I need to do npm install for module not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, npm

I am making a change to someone else's repository. When I try to run the code using node app.js it gives me "Module not found". Do I need to do npm install?

Comment: Yes, `npm install` should be the first thing you run after cloning a repo that uses npm.

Comment: But package.json is already present so why do I need to do npm install.. I have set up the project using docker-compose up. So is npm install necessary?

Comment: Because `npm install` is what is actually going to install those 3rd party libs that your code needs to run.  The `package.json` just defines what `npm` should install, it doesn't actually install anything unless you tell it to.

Comment: but docker sets everything up so why I need to do npm install?

Answer (score 0):

When you clone or fork code from git repo you always want to run `npm install` in the projects root folder.
This will install all necessary dependencies that projects uses